# NSIS: MUI_TEXT_X_TITLE isn't changed at the gui

Tags: nsis

I use `MUI2` with `nsis2` and want to change the labels e.g. at the license page. I don't get warnings, but, the the labels or buttons aren't changed. What could be the error? Do I have the order correctly?

At the MUI docuemntation, they said, I should use `LangString` before the `Pages`, but doesn't work and I get warnings.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE $(license)
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "German" 
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

LangString TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE ${LANG_GERMAN} "Installationsprogramm"
LangString TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Installer"

LicenseLangString license ${LANG_GERMAN} "index_german.txt"
LicenseLangString license ${LANG_ENGLISH} "index_english.txt"

!define MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE "$(TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE)"
```

I could also give more information or code if it wished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page settings need to be set just before the page macro.

> Page settings apply to a single page and should be set before
>   inserting a page macro. The same settings can be used for installer
>   and uninstaller pages. You have to repeat the setting if you want it
>   to apply to multiple pages.

If the text does not change then you used the wrong define or defined it at the wrong place in your code. `MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE` is not a documented MUI2 define.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "foo"
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_TEXT_TOP "bar"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE $(license)

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "German" 

LicenseLangString ...
```